# How do you show that $e^{-a\sqrt{1+\|x\|^2}}$ is in the Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I want to show that $e^{-a\sqrt{1+\|x\|^2}}$ is in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. ($a>0$)

Please tell me proof.

Where,

$$\|x\|^2 = \left(\sum_{j=1}^{d} |x_j|^2\right)$$

$$ f(x) \in \mathcal{S} \overset {\mathrm{def}} {\Leftrightarrow} \displaystyle \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} |x^\alpha\partial^\beta_x f(x)| < \infty $$

$\alpha,\beta$ is multi index notations.

Comment: Hint: Calculate $ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} |x^\alpha\partial^\beta_x f(x)| $ and see if it is finite. No?

Comment: @Paul Thank you for showing hint, but I don't know how to calculate $\partial^\beta_xe^{-a\sqrt{1+\|x\|^2}}$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Hmmm... let $d$=1. When $f(x)=e^{-a\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ ,$f'(x)=-ax(1+x^2)^{-1/2}e^{-a\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. $-ax(1+x^2)^{-1/2}$ is polynomial ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show by induction that every derivative of $f$ is a finite sum of functions of the form

$$p(x)(1+|x|^2)^rf(x).$$

Here $p$ is a polynomial and $r\in \mathbb R.$